# Unity: Disable scroll dragging when scrollbars is hidden

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, scroll, scrollbar

I want to disable mouse dragging and mouse wheel for scroll view when there is no need to scroll (when the scrollbar is hidden or when scrollbar size = 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the movement type to [Elastic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect.MovementType.Elastic.html) change it to [Clamped](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect.MovementType.Clamped.html)